# nesting ConnectionStrings.xxx.config

Tags: visual-studio-2013, connection-string

In Visual Studio 2015 IDE, I have several ConnectionStrings.versionX.config files nested under the main ConnectionStrings.config.  I created some new ones but they are not nested as others.  I also created several configurations using the Configuration Manger.  In the Solution Explorer when I right click the web.conifg the context menu contains an "add config transformation" option. However, the context menu on the right click of ConnectionStrings.config doesn't have that option. Am I missing something?  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "nested"?

Comment: It's like the multiple configuration files (web.xxx.config) are visually nested as sub-tree nodes of the main web.config in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: It's like the multiple configuration files (web.debug.config and web.release.config ) are visually nested as sub-tree nodes of the main web.config in the Solution Explorer. I am trying to visually align the ConnectionStrings.xxx.config as sub-tree nodes of the main ConnectionStrings.config